# cURL stream as standard input for python module

Tags: python, curl, cmd, python-requests

I'm trying to pipe output from a cURL to input for a Python module through the following line in CMD:

```
curl https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/e00fce68515bfa5f850de016/events?access_token=ae40788c6dba577144249fec95afdeadb18e6bec | pythonmodule.py
```

When curl is run by itself (without "`| pythonmodule.py`" it streams data continuously every 30 seconds (it's connected to an Argon IoT with a temperature and humidity sensor) printing the real time temperature and humidity perfectly. But when I try to redirect the output via the | it only seems to work once, it doesn't continuously run the pythonmodule which it should every-time where new data is provided.

I tried to use the library `requests.get()` but since it's a continuous stream it seems to freeze on the `get()`.

Can someone explain how this cURL stream actually works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here that with "only seems to work once" you mean that the command exits after the data is received for the first time. It might be that your python script stops reading after that first line.

Looping over the stdin might solve your issue:

```py
import sys

for n, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
   if line.strip() != "":
      print(n, line)
```

Using a command like :

```
curl -sN https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/e00fce68515bfa5f850de016/events?access_token=ae40788c6dba577144249fec95afdeadb18e6bec | python blah.py
```

Will result in:

```
0 :ok

3 event: SensorVals

4 data: {"data":"{humidity: 30.000000, temp: 24.000000}","ttl":60,"published_at":"2019-11-28T13:50:34.459Z","coreid":"e00fce68515bfa5f850de016"}

9 event: SensorVals

10 data: {"data":"{humidity: 30.000000, temp: 24.000000}","ttl":60,"published_at":"2019-11-28T13:51:04.608Z","coreid":"e00fce68515bfa5f850de016"}

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah.py", line 3, in <module>
    for n, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 4):

Concerning freezing on requests continuous stream you can use `Body Content Workflow` from `requests` to avoid waiting for the whole content to download at once:

```
with requests.get('your_url', stream=True) as response:
    for line in response.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
        if line:
            print(line)
```

Output:

```
:ok
event: SensorVals
data: {"data":"{humidity: 30.000000, temp: 24.000000}","ttl":60,"published_at":"2019-11-28T13:53:04.592Z","coreid":"e00fce68515bfa5f850de016"}
event: SensorVals
data: {"data":"{humidity: 29.000000, temp: 24.000000}","ttl":60,"published_at":"2019-11-28T13:53:34.604Z","coreid":"e00fce68515bfa5f850de016"}
...
```

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow